# Complex Android TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm getting name and a reference number from the database. Now, I want to show data like this

[image]

Here `A` is the name & 1 is the reference number. Already, I have a layout like

```
<ScrollView><RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout></ScrollView>
```

Already, There are other contents in the `RelativeLayout`. So, is this possible to show data like this in a `RelativeLayout`. So my question is

1) is this possible to show data like this ?

2) If yes, then how can I achieve that ? I will be happy, If you give an example.

Comment: You need to take two `TextView`s in `RelativeLayout`. One for Name and one for your reference number. Make them adjcent to each other and give `textSize` of second `TextView` relatively small as compared to the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("A<sup><small>1</small></sup>"));
```

It will Create superscript of given number in  tag.

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Or there is another Way. The Spannable StringBuilder.

Try this,

```
  textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            SpannableStringBuilder spanSupScript = new SpannableStringBuilder("A1 \nB2");
            spanSupScript.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spanSupScript.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan((float)0.75), 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spanSupScript.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 5, 6, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spanSupScript.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan((float)0.75), 5, 6, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spanSupScript.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanSupScript.length(), 0);
            textview.setTextSize(16);
            textview.setText(spanSupScript);
```

Use a TextView, do the above code, and get the output as follows,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add two more TextView to the relative layout and with the help of the tag (As mentioned by @Armaan Stranger ) and add the text dynamically.